# How do I write a function to display the person that has the lowest annual salary with the given data frame? In R

Tags: r

This is my data frame:

```
employee <-c("Susan", "John", "Matthew")
age<- c(30,40,50)
salary<-c(40000, 100000, 60000)

db<-data.frame(employee,age,salary)
```

How can I write a function to display the name of the person that has the lowest annual salary, i.e., `"Susan"`?

Comment: That doesnt work. I want the function to work such that when I execute it, I get "Susan" as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try with `which.min`. It returns the index of minimum value and then if you want the name of the employee you can select the `employee` column.

```
db[which.min(db$salary), "employee"]

#[1] Susan
#Levels: John Matthew Susan
```

As per @Richard's comment, in case of tie you can use

```
db[db$salary == min(db$salary), "employee"]
```

OR

```
db[with(db, salary == min(salary)), "employee"]
```

would be much faster.

Comment: This would only give the first minimum in the case of a tie.  Perhaps `with(db, salary == min(salary))` might be safer for the index

Comment: The second part is missing db$

Comment: @docendodiscimus well, it doesn't require `db$` as we are using `with`

Comment: No. I mean the SECOND code block. You need db$salary there

Comment: Yes, you are right! It worked for me because the `salary` object was already present in my environment. Thanks!

Comment: or `with(db, employee[salary == min(salary))]`

Answer (score 2):

We could use `frank` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(db)[frank(salary)==1]$employee
#[1] Susan
#Levels: John Matthew Susan
```